# Usually first parameter of such methods is named 'mcs'

Tags: python, pycharm, warnings, metaclass

I got a surprising PyCharm warning in the following metaclass

> Usually first parameter of such methods is named 'mcs'

Is this some convention I'm unaware of like naming the first parameter `self` or `cls`? I tried searching SO but didn't find any hit. The code was taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35732111).

[image: screenshot of warning]

```py
class Meta(type):

    def __prepare__(metaclass, cls, bases):
        return dict()

    def __new__(metacls, cls, bases, clsdict):
        return super().__new__(metacls, cls, bases, clsdict)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For metaclasses, the methods that would normally be "class methods" - like `__prepare__` and `__new__` will receive on the first parameter the metaclass itself.

There is no convention about the naming of that parameter. Usually people unaware, or simply not worried, about the full extent of what is really going on with a metaclass, will simply name these `cls` as if it were a normal class and life follows. I believe most IDEs won't recognize anything other, and if the highlighted "correct" use of "cls" and "self" as the first parameter to methods, they might even mark anything else as "wrong". One always has to keep in mind these are just conventions - and linters and syntax highlighters are far less flexible than the human mind (at least currently), and their word should not be taken as the law.

That said, unlike the names "cls" and "self", there is no strong convention for when the first parameter is the metaclass itself - I usually name it `mcls`, but `mcs` would be fine, while `metaclass` is a bit dangerous, as it is a reserved keyword in the class definition itself (when using the `class` statement).

However, it *happens* that the class used in the `metaclass` argument is exactly the one passed to the first argument of the metaclass `__new__` method, so, yes, it might "fix an inconsistency" if the first parameter in a metaclass `__new__` is named `metaclass`. (I never thought about that).

In other words, when defining a class with `class MyClass(ClassA, ClassB, metaclass=MyMeta):` , the `MyMeta` is what is passed in the first parameter of `MyMeta.__new__`, and if it is named `metaclass`, it will be *as if* Python was passing it as a "named parameter". Even though, on the `class` statement side, the `metaclass` name is hardcoded in the language definition, and on the `def __new__` side, whatever name is on the first parameter will be used.

```py
In [98]: class M(type):
    ...:     def __new__(metaclass, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs):
    ...:         return super().__new__(metaclass, name, bases, namespace, **kwargs)
    ...: 

In [99]: class A(metaclass=M): 
    ...:    pass
```

Anyway, as I said, I am usually happy with `mcls`.

And conversely, and equally important: any other methods on a metaclass, that on an ordinary class would be `self` will be receiving as parameter the `class` created with the metaclass - So it is usual to name those `cls` instead of `self`, as it is easier to keep in mind what an instance of the metaclass represents.

Thus, in a metaclass for the methods `__init__`, `__getattr__`, `__call__` and whatever one finds useful, the first argument makes sense as being `cls` instead of `self`.

Going back to one of your snippets:

```py
class Meta(type):
    @classmethod
    def __prepare__(mcls, metaclass, cls, bases):
        return dict()

    def __new__(metacls, cls, bases, clsdict):
        return super().__new__(metacls, cls, bases, clsdict)
```

As I commented, you may call the first argument `metacls`, but the **second** argument to `__new__` and `__prepare__` should be `name` not `cls`. Again: Python passes these as ordered arguments, so it would *work* if you named it `cls`, but its contents are the declared class name as a string, nonetheless.  On one hand, the `cls` name normally designates the class itself, and it does not even *exist* when these methods are called - it will exist only from the point where you call `super().__new__` inside the `__new__`  metaclass method.

As for the fourth parameter, you call `clsdict`, I know of no strong convention - `clsdict`is clear enough, as would be `namespace` - but over the years, I've been using simply `dct`, and have used `ns` on occasion as well.

And finally, as stated above, I would not expect PyCharm or any other style highlighter (or "corrector") to understand better than me what are my intentions with a metaclass: I will just ignore them.

Answer (score 5):

The preferred value could be changed in `File | Settings | Editor | Inspections | Python | Methods having troubles with first parameter`, see screenshot:

[image: Inspection settings]

Comment: Pycharm is a joke if it allows this to be "configured" but just offer a choice of two configurations, and not a free field there. (Or at least the set with all reasonable options)

Answer (score 3):

I think metaclasses are used much less frequently than regular classes, so it's only logical that a convention as strong and widespread as `self` and `cls` doesn't exist.

Google search results are slightly in favor of `mcs`:

[`__new__(mcs`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22__new__%28mcs%22) 3490 results

[`__new__(mcls`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22__new__%28mcls%22) 2230 results

[`__new__(metacls`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22__new__%28metacls%22) 1940 results

[`__new__(metaclass`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22__new__%28metaclass%22) 919 results

Personally, I would be leaning towards `metacls` as it's more descriptive and feels more consistent with `cls` to me.